# Replace every instance of a word in the dom with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to parse with a chrome extension I am making, and replace ever instance of one word with another. This is what I have that is not working for me

```
function jamify() {
  $("body").html().replace(/James/g,"Jamie");
}
```

Comment: Try this: `$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/James/g,"Jamie"));`

Comment: @ChrisG Drat, you beat me to it...  Replace does not replace in place...

Comment: @ChrisG Keep in mind that while this does what he asked for, it will break a lot of other stuff. Run the code on this website and the WYSIWYG editor gets a second toolbar. All event listeners will also break. All scripts in the body get re-executed.

Comment: Note that this is a bad idea if you have any event bindings on any of the elements. It will re-parse the entire DOM, and all bindings and property modifications will be lost.

Comment: True, I just wanted to post a quick fix. A better way is to iterate over all text nodes.

Comment: thanks guys! is there a way to make it only replace the inner HTML occurences of the word?

Comment: maybe use text() instead of html() not sure if the DOM is recreated that way. NM it would break any nested structure unless you looped over all the elements (expensive performance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and rather dirty replacement of `.html()` has a couple of downsides.

- it will actually replace the entire DOM structure, removing any event bindings if these are not bound 'live' on an element higher up the hierarchy
- it will replace a lot more than you may expect. You should be safe with 'James' to 'Jamie', but it may get funky when 'em' wants to be named 'emmy' and suddenly certain italic texts get straightened out.

A better way is to replace only strings in actual text nodes, as jQuery is not (currently) a tag on the question, I assume vanilla javascript is a proper option.

```js
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.body,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, {
    acceptNode: function(node) {
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
  },
  false
);

while (walker.nextNode()) {
  walker.currentNode.data = walker.currentNode.data.replace(/James/g, 'Jamie');
}
```

```html
<!--  James  -->
<div data-name="James" class="James">
  James
</div>
```

This example will *only* touch the actual text element(s), the comment and both the attributes (`data-name` and `class`) will not get replaced, so it remains safe to have javascript and/or css referring to these.

Comment: This should be the Accepted answer and clearly explains why. Good Answer

Answer (score 1):

I am showing it this way to show that you have to call some function to reset the html to the newly replaced string

NOTE: This will destroy any DOM event you had attached before the replace

you can shorten this by nesting the call all into one if you wanted

```js
function jamify() {
 
  var str = $(".test").html();
  console.log('jamify', str);
  str2 = str.replace(/James/g,"Jamie");
  $(".test").html(str2);
  
  //to simplify it could be done this way too
  //$(".test").html($(".test").html().replace(/James/g,"Jamie"))
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  //alert('ready');
  $('.inner').click(function(){console.log('inner click')})
  //Yea!, my click event is all good.
  jamify();
  //Now all your inner click EVENT is broken so this is not good
  //solution if there are any events attached in your DOM
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <p>James is here</p>
  <div class="inner">this div is James</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry others i was working on the snippet and didn't see the solution posted in comments

Answer (score 1):

If the words are in the textContent you can try:

```js
var all = document.querySelectorAll('.test')
//using .test as a wrapper section, try using body in production as selector (in the snippets it breaks)

all.forEach(x => x.textContent = x.textContent.replace(/James/gi, "Jamie"))
// keep in mind forEach for nodes has limited support, tested  in chrome
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>James is here</p>
  <div >this div is James</div>
</div>
```